How to check Network Speed of specific Interface
I could test using IPERF linux Utility. But I want to specifically send/receive data on particular interface. Is there any way to do that?
I tried using iperf -c server_ip -B {IP_address of my Mellanox Device}.
Still I am getting speed of 9XX M/s where if the traffic was routed through Mellanox IFace it would be above 16 Gb/s.
Note: I am not setting ips manually. The DHCP server assigns me automatically.
Thanks

After the IP you pass to -B, put %dev, where dev is the name of the device you want to use.

iperf -c 192.168.10.254 -t 10 -B 192.168.10.223%enp4s0f0
Output : error: Name or service not known.  I tried all the iface names possible and I am getting same error. I don't have anything in my /etc/network/interface custom IP settings.

@KaleemKhattak What version of iperf are you using, and how did you install it? If the answer to the second part is "from your distro's package manager", then what distro and version are you on?

iperf version 2.0.9 (1 June 2016) pthreads...  I didn't setup this OS so hard to tell how things got setup.       => uname -a Linux debian 5.10.0-16-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.127-1 (2022-06-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Both your iperf version and your Debian version appear to be ancient. Update and then try again.

After Updating and trying -B Device_IP_ADDR%Device it would say bad file descriptor. without %Device iperf3 would work fine. I removed iperf2 from both client and host before installing iperf3.
